# Printing Unwanted Characters with PHP "preg_match"

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am using PHP "preg_match". I want to print the incorrect characters in the name. How can I do that ?

"preg_match" If there are characters other than the allowed values with, I want to print the unwanted characters on the screen. What kind of add should be in the code below?

**MY Code:**

```
<?php 
    $name = "He/llo W+or_ld Test=Code";

    if( preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z ]/', $name) ){

       echo "Unavailable Characters: ";   // What changes should be made here?

    }
?>
```

**Desired Result:**

```
Unavailable Characters: /+_=
```

Comment: You can use preg_match_all and then print the matches collection

Comment: @Thefourthbird How can I do that. Is there any sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$name = "He/llo W+or_ld Test=Code";
if( preg_match_all('/[^a-zA-Z ]/', $name, $res) ){
  echo "Unavailable Characters: " . implode('', $res[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
Unavailable Characters: /+_=
```

See [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/e5bAq)

**NOTES**:

- Using `preg_match_all`, you extract all match occurrences
- You need to pass the third argument to `preg_match_all` to actually store the matches there (here, I pass `$res`)
- You need to `implode()` the `$res[0]` array that contains the match values.